# DataFormatter is not reading the comma separated numeric value

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am reading the values from excel file, so i am using the below code for reading the values.

```
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
fmt.formatCellValue(cell);
```

but this case is failing when the numeric value is comma seperated like `2,345,678`. it's taking 2 only.
i want to read full value like 2345678

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). If you want to improve the chance of getting an answer, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you post more information about the question? I believe this a question regarding apache POI. Please add a poi tag. Can you tell what is the type of the cell? Also try using BuiltInDataFormats and see if that helps.

Comment: added the poi. and cell type is number

Comment: Your code is doing nothing with the string returned by `fmt.formatCellValue(cell)`. So not clear where your problem is.

Comment: fmt.formatCellValue(cell) is returning all types are correct like string, int, short, double etc. but when reading the numeric value contains comma seperated(1,234 or 1,111,111) then only the problem,

Comment: No, you are wrong. [DataFormatter.formatCellValue](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29) will always return a `String`, never a numeric value.